# Is it possible to add .NET code (sections) to a WordPress site?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, wordpress

Our shop is primarily .NET but because of the lack of any really good popular .NET CMS products, we have chosen to use WordPress (and Drupal at times) for our public facing sites.

I realize this is highly subjective, but it is the conclusion we came to for our purposes. One could certainly make a case for DotNetNuke and others, but that is another conversation.

I would like to know if I can integrate small components into WordPress sites, primarily to do simple forms (logon, lost password, contact us, change user settings, etc...)

Can I do this with an iFrame or another method that I am not thinking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only simple way to do this is to make  `<iframe>` tags pointing to ASPX files.

Comment: For passing data to the iframes, you could use JavaScript to set the source parameter of the iframe, and pass in relevant parameters via the query string. For data inbound to the CMS, you'd probably rely on a relevant API/web service called via AJAX or a postback from the iframe itself.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could, I wouldn't recommend it. Since you are talking about forms, could you not just write php or javascript that communicates with the .net files? I'm not to sure about how Web development in .net works.

Comment: Yes, I could write PHP but only about 10% of our developers know PHP. It makes more sense to us, from a productivity point of view, to use .NET.

Comment: I see, Iframes seem like the best way to go then, or if you could pass information to your aspx scripts using POST or GET that is another possibilty.

Good luck on finding a solution